# How to convert Sprite to UIImage to post it on Facebook?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using below code to convert sprite to `UIImage` in `cocos2dx` version 3.2.
and post on facebook , i will check on facebook that show black backgroung image.

// this code `ObjCCalls.mm` class

```
Sprite *sprite=(Sprite*)GameManager::sharedGameManager()->playerImageOnFb.at(2);

RenderTexture* rend = RenderTexture::create(sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh());

sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0));
rend->begin();
sprite->visit();
rend->end();

Image *image=rend->newImage();

AppController* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

UIImage *tempImage=[appDelegate imageFromCCImage:image] ;

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                               tempImage,@"message",

                               nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {

 }];
```

// this code in `AppDeleagate.mm`

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromCCImage:(cocos2d::Image *) ccImage
{

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                              ccImage->getData(),
                                                              ccImage->getDataLen() * bytesPerPixel,
                                                              NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    NSUInteger scanWidth = ccImage->getWidth() * bytesPerPixel;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(ccImage->getWidth(),
                                        ccImage->getHeight(),
                                        8,
                                        bytesPerPixel * 8,
                                        scanWidth,
                                        colorSpaceRef,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        NO,
                                        renderingIntent);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return image;
}
```